# Hide Disqus Comments Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, hide, disqus

Currently I have set up a button to Show Disqus Comments

I would also like to have a button to Hide the Disqus Comments after they have been loaded

My current code for the show button is:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<div id="disqus_loader" class="button" style="text-align: center">
  <button onclick='$.ajaxSetup({cache:true});$.getScript("http://westonganger.disqus.com/embed.js");$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});                    
  $("#disqus_loader").remove();'>Show Comments</button>
</div>
```

I am just delving into javascript and jquery, so if someone could help me that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$("#disqus_loader").remove();
```

To:

```
$("#disqus_loader").toggle();
```

This will switch between `display: none` and `display: block`.
Calling `remove()` removes the content from the DOM completely.